# Does freelance work count as "real" experience?

Tags: freelance

I am working as a data scraping Freelance developer with Python. I have been working for the last 5 years in building automation and scraping scripts with Python. For the last 3 years, I have been learning Django and created several projects in Django and hosted some of these apps. Some of these apps are used by my clients. I am now 32 years old. I never worked in any IT company till now. Because I was a teacher. I am from India.

Now, I want to join an IT company as a Python Django Backend/Full-Stack developer. In my resume, how many years of experience should I write? Do you think I am still fresher for companies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are two types of experience we gain from working for a company, technical experience and company work environment experience. A freelancer may have technical experience but not the work environment experience. There may be tools and practices in the company that you are totally new to.

There is a second type of experience one gets as a freelancer, entrepreneurial thinking. This will actually help when working for a small company where you can work directly with the sales team. It hurts when working for a large company where you are expected to be a "cog in the machine" and not trying to solve customer problems in new ways.